# how can I use laravel echo without laravel framework and npm

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-echo

Is any way to use Laravel-echo library without Laravel framework and NPM?
just use `<script>` tag and add library to my project.

Comment: Why would you? It's specific to Laravel.

Comment: the fact is i want to use it without vue and gulp . output of the way that Documentation is describe is very heavy js file with a lot of unwanted library like Vue,webpack,bootstrap.scss,.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the **echojs** without **laravel** and **npm**.

**echojs** is a **Js** library,

Follow these steps to create **echo.js** file:

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"
window.Echo = Echo; // inject the echo js into the browser
```

compile this with **gulp** using following code

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir(mix => {
    mix
       .webpack('echo.js','public/assets/js/echo.js');
});
```

You can use this **public/assets/js/echo.js** file in any projects.

If you're not comfortable with above steps, go to our repository https://github.com/W2S-Solutions/laravel-echo-js-compiled/ and copy echo.js to use anywhere in your project

Comment: For laravel 5.7 use `mix.js('echo.js', 'assets/js/echo.js')`. By default `mix`  will point to "public", you can change it with `mix.setPublicPath()`